# In Gutenberg Block Editor If I Update/Save the Page My Custom Query String is Remove but I Want to Stay It In The URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When I go to edit option with WordPress Gutenberg block editor I passes a custom query string to URL for my development need. But If I update or save the page then my custom query string is gone. How can I make stay the Query String in my URL?

Please see the image to understand properly.

[image]

Thank you
Sharif

I'm trying to make stay the custom query in my URL if I'm update/save the page.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the extra parameters added to the URL persist. If you reload the URL or save/update the page, `post=2&action=edit&action_id=4` remains. The issue described is more likey the test parameter conflicting with an existing function or script. Alternatively, you may need to use the [JavaScript Block API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/) if you are attempting to update the post or post data via the Editor.

If you are trying to access the query parameters in your JavaScript or Gutenberg Block, you can test in the console what query args are present with:

**JavaScript**

```js
wp.url.getQueryArgs(window.location.href);
```

**Result:**

```js
{post: '2', action: 'edit', action_id: '4'}
```

The [@wordpress/url](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-url/) package also contains many useful functions for manipulating URLs and parameters.